# Updating matlab GUI out of a function called by the GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I made a program with which I try to do automated measurements. The program works so far, but I'm not sure if it is the proper way to do it.

The program consists of two functions:

- meassure 
  (measures a single device, plots the data and saves it to an Excel file)
- measureAutomatically (uses a matrix with 0 and 1, moves to all the devices in the matrix and if there is a 1 in the device matrix, it will trigger the measure function. With the parameters: Excel filename and handle for the graph/axes to where to plot)

I also added a GUI with which the device matrix gets generated. A push button triggers the measureAutomatically function.

The GUI should show the current measurement (in real time, not after it is finished) and it should change the color of a rectangle in another axes from gray to green/red if the measurement was successful or not (like an indicator what is done a a given point)

So far I give the measure function the handle of the axis to plot and format the plot in the measure function.

I'm not sure on what to do with updating of the rectangle thing. At the moment the measureAutomatically function gets the result of the measurement and then looks for the reactangle (findobj by tag) and changes the color.

I'd like to keep the functions independent from the GUI though (which isn't the case right now). So should I rather call a function in the GUI to change the rectangle? But how would I do that? Or what is the proper way to do something like this. I'm still a beginner in matlab, but I don't just want to get it to work but also want to learn the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would certainly make a function that accepts the status of the measurement and do whatever needed afterwards

```
    function updateStatus(status, isGUI)
    if isGUI
        if status
            % Change the rectangle color to green
        else
            % Change the rectangle color to red
        end
    else
        if status
            % Do something else
        else
            % Do something else
        end
    end
```

You can also pass the handles to the objects in figure `UserData` or use `setappdata/getappdata`  and reference objects directly, not by looking for them by `findobj`.  But that is matter of preference.

Comment: thanks, but I think I haven't got completely how this would work. This function would be in the GUI m-file or a separate file? And then called by the measureAutomatically function?

Comment: You can place this function into your GUI m-file, or have it separately in the same folder (or on the Matlab path).  Again, it is matter of preference, whether all functions are in one file, or in separate files.  I prefer have them in separate files.  The `updateStatus` will be called by your `measureAutomatically` function.  I have included `isGUI` option which can be used to switch to some different indication of the status (write it to a file, for example).  You can implement any logic, what to do after you receive status of the measurement.